# access python property from within class

Tags: python

I'm new to Python properties. I want to use them in order to create a "setter" that ensures that a property value is within its allowed range when setting the corresponding attribute.

Typical usage examples I found look like this:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = None
    def getx(self):
        print "+++ getx()"
        return self.__x
    def setx(self, v):
        if (v > 0):
            print "+++ setx({0})".format(v)
            self.__x  =  v
    def delx(self):
        print "+++ delx()"
        del self.__x
    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "Me property 'x'.")
```

In this simple example, the setter "setx" ensures that only positive values can be assigned to the attribute self.__x. So far so good. However, when looking at this code, I started wondering if I could use properties from within the class itself. For example, I wonder if I could have the following constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.x = None
```

in order to get the setter called right from within the constructor in order to ensure that the attribute self.__x is being set to a valid value. Going a little further, I wonder if I could do the same from everywhere else within the class (with the obvious exception of the getter and setter themselves). If so, is this considered good programming practice? If not, what alternatives are there? I'm really confused about this.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no difference between accessing a property from within or outside of a class (and trying this in a python interpreter would have taken less time than writing this question). If you want to know if it's better to access the property or the actual attribute, this probably depends on the specific use case - in your example, replacing `self.__x = None` with `self.x = None` would make no sense as the setter only sets values > 0 and `None > 0 == False`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually tried this before submitting the question and saw that it worked but, since I couldn't find examples of code doing this, I wasn't sure whether this was good practice and/or whether there were any catches I wasn't aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I started wondering if I could use properties from within the class
>   itself.

Yes, you can use the setter/getter in the constructor

```
def __init__(self):
    self.x = None
```

This is fine (although in this particular case it would fail because `None > 0 == False`, a condition which you may want to report through a log or raising an exception). There can be reasons for not wanting to use the accessors in the constructor. For example, if they require expensive operations which are not useful to perform while in the constructor (e.g. lazy loading, as in delaying actual initialisation until it is really needed).